# Yarn Start does not work for me in the terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am attempting to View my Local host Browser using the "Yarn Start" In the Terminal, however when i try to open it i get an error that says "Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 6:0-56

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/DirectoryComponent' in '/Users/keithquinney/Desktop/NucampFolder/3-React/nucampsite/src'"

Any ideas as to what the problem could be , as i retraced my steps to see if i was missing something including looking at my fellow classmates code to compare and i don’t [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0UZz.png)  seem to find the source of the problem. ** Please see the Screenshot attached** Thank you

Comment: Check if you have DirectoryComponent inside ./components as that's the error exactly.

Comment: I double checked, and all the files are in the correct location